# How to fix division method to get correct output?

Tags: java

I'm getting problem in division i.e. when I divide 9000000000/9 without type casting I'm getting 10^9 but when I cast it to float it is giving 9.9999994E8

```
long n = 10;
long sum = 9000000000;
float mean = ((float)sum)/(n-1);
```

Can anyone help me, please? I'm not getting where I'm lacking and I have a time limitation to do research that's why I'm here to get a quick response.

Comment: Use `BigDecimal`

Comment: Instead of float?

Comment: Yes; a `float` does not have sufficient precision to perform your operation precisely enough for an integer-accurate result.

Comment: Use `BigDecimal` instead of the two `long` and call the `divide`-method that returns a new `BigDecimal` with the result.

Comment: Thanks, I got the mistake, Instead of big decimal I used double and I got the answer.
I don't know how I have done get these kind mistakes at this level.
Sometimes in hurry, I do these kinds of mistake.

Answer (score 3):

9000000000 is treated as an in and is too big, you to do 9000000000L. Try BigDecimal:

```
    long n = 10;
    BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal("9000000000");
    BigDecimal mean = sum.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(n-1));
```

Comment: You have the correct conclusion (use big decimal) but the wrong reason; `9000000000` fits into a `long` easily. The maximum value a `long` can have is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: Well unless you specify it is a long by putting an L at the end it will be considered as an int and treated as too big. But yea the wording I used is not accurate

Comment: Thanks, @anthonyyaghi for help. But without putting L at the end it will be treated as long.